# How to iterate on a custom number field on an account using flows and not trigger

Tags: visual-workflow, loop

Creates the number of contacts which are equal to the number which we will enter in the Number of Locations field on the Account Object. This is the trigger but i have been assigned to convert this into flow main problem that occurs is that The number of Locations field is a number and not a variable how can I iterate over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically there is a way to achieve this even via Flow.

'Number_Of_Contacts__c' on account.

Step 1) Create a collection variable : ListOfNumbers (Data type as number) 
Step 2) Create a variable : InitialNumberOfContacts (Data type as number)
Step 3) First check with a decision element that your `InitialNumberOfContacts` is equal to `Number_Of_Contacts__c`
If `No` then have an assignment node and append a number to this variable. `ListOfNumbers` and increment `InitialNumberOfContacts` by 1.

Also connect this assignemnt back to decision. **//THIS IS VERY IMP.**

This will keep on iterating and append a number to `ListOfNumbers`.

**Just FYI : You can even use this decision loop to create Contacts records**

And when the decision has resulted in `Yes` then you can start creating your contacts by looping on the collection variable, but dont insert here.

UPDATE: As per below feedback, I have removed DML in loop and shared the modified version of the flow.

[image]

To make the flow shorter and as suggested above in FYI.
Here is you can loop on to the a number too with a recursive decision tree.

[image]

The key is to increment the initial counter like this in decision.

[image]

Comment: The loop is unnecessary, and perhaps even "harmful" in the traditional sense, because you're actually burning up DML very quickly. Better to do everything at once.

Comment: Yes, i wrote it as a note. But agreed that DML should not happen in loop.

Comment: Updated my flow diagram based on feedback comment from @sfdcfox

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Based on this [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdihFUAR/flowallow-for-loop-to-run-specified-number-of-times), seems currently we can't set the numerical value for `Loop` component's iteration action in Salesforce flow at this moment. And as per document loop iteration is depends on the collection variable items..

> Loop: Start a loop path for iterating over items in a collection variable.For each iteration, the flow temporarily stores the item in the loop variable. To execute actions on each item’s field values, use other elements in the loop.

Hope it helps.